# Working with large KML files

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have work with a ~23MB kml file. The task is to show the polygons (~5000 shapes) online on a google-map and show some information in a sidebar when a shape is clicked. All the stuff can be done in JS I think. So if I use the large kml file on the page it will load all the 23MB at once and is very slow. It is not necessary to show all polygons at once, so it would be possible to show only parts of it at a certain zoom level. What strategies are common to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe first try to compress it as a kmz file?

Comment: This results in a 3,6 MB file. It is also too big too load it at once. I´m thinking about splitting it to different districts and get a a district layer in front of it, and show only the details if it is zoomed. Other ideas are very welcome!